# Replication with pgadmin+slony+ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.2, database-replication, pgadmin, slony

I am using postgres 9.2 and slony1-2.0.0-rc1.The problem is that whenever i create slony-I cluster it shows slony-I creation scripts not available, only joining possible.

I have also set the binary path usr/bin/postgresql but still its not working.Please help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open pgadmin,go to options,then click binary paths and set the path of Slony-I path as 
`/usr/share/slony1` in ubuntu.
If this does not work your postgres version is not compatible with slony version.

You can see [this post](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pgAdmin-1-18-0-slony-I-2-2-0-PG-9-3-td5772774.html).

Comment: Thanks. It Worked to an extent but now it shows following error while creating a new cluster:                                                                                                                                                                                     ERROR:  function _sample.storenode(integer, unknown, boolean) does not exist
LINE 6413: SELECT _sample.storeNode(99, 'admin_node', false);
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.